# Does centrifugal force transfer in a vacuum?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, vacuum, centrifugal-force

Let's say there is a closed cylinder floating in space, experiencing no acceleratory forces.  Suppose the cylinder is 200 ft tall and has a 75 ft radius (arbitrary selections).  Lastly, let's say there is a stationary ball floating 100 ft from the base of the cylinder and 35 ft from the side, offset from the very center.

If the volume of the cylinder is a vacuum, containing no gas, and the cylinder began revolving, would any centrifugal forces by applied to the ball?  My assumption is no, since there is, as far as I can tell, no gas or other medium to transfer the energy of the momentum of rotation to the ball in a vacuum.

If there were air within the cylinder, I would expect the ball to move to the side of the cylinder, and I suppose this is because the gas would transfer the energy of revolution to the ball in some way.  I'm not sure how this works - help me out!

So what would happen?  Would the ball remain stationary in an airless cylinder or would it be drawn to the edge of the cylinder?

Answer (score 1):

At first, the ball would stay exactly where it was. All the effects we commonly encounter when dealing with rotating bodies (centrifugal force, coriolis force, etc.) occur because the rotating object interacts with things in or on it, usually by friction. Since in the example you give, there is no such interaction between the ball and the cylinder, there will initially be no centrifugal force.

If we want to be very precise, the ball will slowly be attracted to the side of the cylinder that is closer, because the gravitational field in a hollow cylinder (unlike in a hollow sphere) does not completely vanish. In the cylinder, this field is independet of its rotation, so this will happen regardless of whether it was spinning or not. As soon as the ball and the cylinder come into contact, the friction between them will start dragging the ball along. Then the cylinder will exert a centripetal force on the ball, further pushing it onto the inside wall.

Answer (score 0):

In the reference frame of the cylinder, the ball would experience a centrifugal force, since every object in a non-inertial reference frame experiences the pseudo-forces associated with that reference frame. However, if the ball is stationary in an inertial reference frame, then it must be moving in uniform circular motion in the rotating reference frame. The reason for this is that the [Coriolis force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coriolis_force) has twice the magnitude of the centrifugal force and points in the opposite direction, thus providing the centripetal force necessary for circular motion in the rotating frame. This circular motion in the rotating frame, with the opposite angular velocity as that of the cylinder w.r.t. the inertial frame, corresponds to the ball being stationary in the inertial frame.